# No UTf-8 when write IPTC data in JPG with iptcembed

Tags: php, utf-8, iptc

I use this function

```
function iptc_make_tag($rec, $data, $value){
    $length = strlen($value);
    $retval = chr(0x1C) . chr($rec) . chr($data);

   if($length < 0x8000)
   {
      $retval .= chr($length >> 8) .  chr($length & 0xFF);
   }
      else
   {
       $retval .= chr(0x80) . 
               chr(0x04) . 
               chr(($length >> 24) & 0xFF) . 
               chr(($length >> 16) & 0xFF) . 
               chr(($length >> 8) & 0xFF) . 
               chr($length & 0xFF);
   }

    return $retval . $value;
```

}

(from http://php.net/manual/de/function.iptcembed.php)

to write captions in my jpgs.
Every Umlaut and other special chars are wrong when I read the jpgs with Picasa/Picasaweb.

Is this function not ready for unicode?
How can I save utf-8 encode strings in jpgs?

Thanks for your help,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

I had to write the 1:90 IPTC field to make my UTF-8 strings display correctly in Photoshop. Assuming you assemble the the IPTC-data in a variable called $iptc you should start with the following three lines to ensure correct UTF-8-handling:

```
// These two lines ensure that UTF8-Encoding will work (set the 1:90 field in the envelop)
// @see http://cpanforum.com/threads/2114 for a hint
$utf8seq = chr(0x1b) . chr(0x25) . chr(0x47);
$length = strlen($utf8seq);
$iptc = chr(0x1C) . chr(1) . chr('090') . chr($length >> 8) . chr($length & 0xFF) . $utf8seq;
```

Aftewards you can continue adding IPTC-fields e.g. with the iptc_make_tag function as described in the example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php and finally embed them into your JPEG:

```
// Embed the IPTC data
$content = iptcembed($iptc, $path);
```

Hope this saves somebody else the research and debugging I had to do today...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is that strlen() is not multi-byte aware - it assumes the input is single-byte encoded. Consider using [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/mb_strlen) instead.

Also, `chr()` is ASCII-only.

I'm not a binary guru, though, and I know nothing about IPTC data, so I'm not exactly sure what else this function is doing and where else there could be UTF-8 issues.

Comment: The statement "chr() is ASCII-only" doesn't make much sense. `chr` is encoding-agnostic, it just ["packs"](http://php.net/pack) a number between 0 and 0xFF.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not enocoding-aware for bytes above 0x7F.  If you use `chr()` to do character comparisons, this can lead some unexpected results depending on the encoding of your source files.